# Coordinate search

Tags: php, mysql, database

Have it almost working now. I can get results in the table but for some reason, they are not quite right.

I search coords x 100 & y 100

I get results of x 1-25 & y 1-25 only rather than x 74-125 & y 74-125

> 

```
<?php

$x = $_POST['x'];
$y = $_POST['y'];

mysql_connect ("localhost","user","pass")  or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db ("db");


$res = mysql_query("select * FROM table WHERE (x between $x-25 AND $x+25) AND (y BETWEEN $y-25 AND $y+25)");

 echo "<table border='1' align='center' cellpadding='5'>";
    echo "<tr> <th>City Name</th> <th>X</th> <th>Y</th> </tr>";

    // loop through results of database query, displaying them in the table
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $res )) {

            // echo out the contents of each row into a table
echo "<tr>";
echo '<td>' . $row['cityname'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['x'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $row['y'] . '</td>';
    echo "</tr>";
    } 

      // close table>
    echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: So far I have xysearch.html

Comment: `select * from table where (x between myX-25 and myX+25) AND (y between myY-25 and myY+25)`?

Comment: Is the myX the name of the input field on the form?

Comment: @Jon: that would give 2,601 squares (ie. 51^2).

Comment: @MarkBannister I assumed a square radius of 25 squares based on what I saw in the question, if every square doesn't have something put there, the result set wouldn't be as large though.

Comment: @PaulHesketh: Do you want the results to be returned from an area that is 25 squares in total area, an area that is within +/- 25 squares in either direction (so 2,601 squares in total), an area that is 25 squares in radius, or something else?

Comment: if a radius of 12.5 (25 squares around the selected) change the `+` and `-` values to `12` instead of `25`

Comment: What happens if you type the query directly in to mysql after logging in and selecting your database.  Is the name of the table with this information `my_dbase`? as that seems rather misleading. ^^  Also, with your edit, you don't need anything pertaining to `$data` anymore ^^

Comment: A grid 50x50 with me in middle, thus 25 North, South, East & West

Comment: 50x50 has a 4 square middle, the grid would have to be odd in order to provide a 1 square middle - so what I've put is a 51x51 square grid. ^^  Also, did you test the query in mysql command line with real numbers instead of variables to see if you got anything?

Comment: Yes, I see your point, it would need to be 51x51. My mistake. I already have a search page where it you can search by cityname and that works fine. It displays the cityname and its x,y coords. Trying to find citynames from a particular coord is proving to be so much more difficult. My latest attempt & script is now in original question. Many thanks for your help Jon

Comment: @PaulHesketh see my updated [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15849607/1745573) and click the SQL Fiddle link at the bottom to see it in action. The code you have appears right, unless maybe you have the table name wrong - or an error with your user/pass or `select_db`. ^^  And you're welcome. EDIT: And please comment on the answer so I can get a notification when you reply - would make my responses speedier. =]

Comment: Updated now, kinda working

Comment: I read about using && rather than the word AND. Would this be affecting it

Comment: @PaulHesketh Please reply in my answer below so I get notified of your responses.  The word `AND` should be used in MySQL, `&&` in PHP. ^^  What do you mean 'kinda working'? Oh! You removed the value assignment of `x` and `y`.  Add those back from my answer: `$x = (intval)$_POST['fld_x'];`, etc ^^

Comment: @PaulHesketh Check my answer again, posted the full code that should work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I give you this, remember that doing it in the fashion you are opens you wide up to SQL Injection, and that you should really use PDO or similar for prepared statements.  That being said:

```
$x = (intval)$_POST['fld_x'];
$y = (intval)$_POST['fld_y'];

$res = mysql_query("select * FROM my_dbase WHERE (x between $x-25 AND $x+25) AND (y BETWEEN $y-25 AND $y+25)");
$data = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $data[] = $row;
}
```

Then do what you will with the `$data`

Example [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1734c/1)

**EDIT**

To make sure the database is connecting properly, please change/add the following where needed:

```
if(!mysql_select_db ("dbase")) {
    die(mysql_error());
}
```

after after `$res = mysql_query...` put:

```
if(!$res) {
    die("Query Failed: ".mysql_error());
}
```

**EDIT**

The full code for you based on what you currently have:

You showed the HTML earlier as:

```
<form action="xysearch.php" method="get">
<label>X Coord
<input type="text" name="fld_x" />
</label>
<label>Y Coord
<input type="text" name=fld_y" />
</label>
<input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

and the PHP would be:

```
<?php

$x = (intval)$_POST['fld_x'];
$y = (intval)$_POST['fld_y'];

mysql_connect ("localhost","user","pass")  or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db ("db");


$res = mysql_query("select * FROM table WHERE (x between $x-25 AND $x+25) AND (y BETWEEN $y-25 AND $y+25)");

 echo "<table border='1' align='center' cellpadding='5'>";
 echo "<tr> <th>City Name</th> <th>X</th> <th>Y</th> </tr>";

// loop through results of database query, displaying them in the table
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $res )) {
    // echo out the contents of each row into a table
    echo "<tr>";
    echo '<td>' . $row['cityname'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['x'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['y'] . '</td>';
    echo "</tr>";
} 

// close table>
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: @paulhesketh Please response here - so I get notified of your responses, also - add the `$x=` and `$y=` that I have in the answer here.

Comment: Well, that should work.  Stayed up to try and get it working for you - though you don't respond here to help me help you.  My last edit should make it work for you.

Comment: I'm on ipad and its not doing what it should I think. Thanks for all your help

Comment: if you add the `$x=(intval)$_POST['fld_x'];` and such back and haven't changed your HTML form, it should. And you're welcome.  If someone does get you an answer here that does work - don't forget to accept it, not having any accepted answers on your questions deters people from wanting to help. ^^

Comment: I didn't mean accept this one - it didn't get it working for you. =P

Comment: Lol, it got me further along to achieving my gosl

Comment: @PaulHesketh No problem!  Glad you finally got it going. ^^

Comment: @PaulHesketh haha!  That makes sense, I hadn't even gotten to thinking of that part yet.

Comment: do you know of any good sites to learn php, i am learning slowly, but hate asking for help

Comment: [Here](http://www.montanaprogrammer.com/learn-php/beginning-php-part1/) is a decent one.  One of the best places is actually looking through http://php.net as the user comments help understand some functions you may not know.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM cityname
WHERE (x between".$_POST['search']."-25 AND ".$_POST['search']."+25)
AND (y between".$_POST['search']."-25 AND ".$_POST['search']."+25)";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Pythagoras theorem as you want the circle to have a radius of 25

So the query would be

```
SELECT cityname, x, y FROM my_database
WHERE SQRT((x - centre_x) * (x - centre_x) + (y - centre_y) * (y - centre_y)) <=25
```

Where centre_x, centre_y is the location that you have entered

Comment: While this is true, he did specify squares around, rather than circular.  Nice answer for a true radius select though. ^^

Comment: @Jon - he said "within 25 squares". With you answer if the city if 25 squares to the left and 25 squares up how many squares would that be? Your answer would say it is 25 squares away. Please get a grid and do aa little counting!

Comment: I made a comment on the actual question for doing it within 12 on each side, I'm just going with "with the 25 squares around that coordinate" and had assumed it to be a square radius for my answer.  I wasn't saying anything bad about your answer, I liked it - especially for the true circular effect. Reading my comment it may not have come across that way, for that, I apologize. I just think the question isn't well written. =] (but I don't believe my comment deserved the blatant rudeness of your reply. ^^)

Comment: @Jon - I did not intend to be rude but your answer is incorrect (even using the Manhattan metric. To go 25 left and 25 up requires 35 squares (blocks) to get there. i.e. not "within 25 squares".

Comment: Very true.  He said he was lost on a question that he didn't seem to know how to ask, my intent was really to get him started rather than provide a full working answer. - never imagined this question would get this much attention.

Comment: True, and it really depends on his use.  I was more basing my answer from the basic map that I created for a game before in which the area needed to be square as it displayed in a square. (Granted this was a game that we made in 2003/2004 for the browser) Though, that is what I had assumed he was going for. ^^

Comment: @jon I just assumed that within is like "x is within 5 miles of my house". Anyway. Lunchtime.

Comment: True, and it really depends on his use. I was more basing my answer from the basic map that I created for a game before in which the area needed to be square as it displayed in a square. (Granted this was a game that we made in 2003/2004 for the browser) Though, that is what I had assumed he was going for............... YES, this would be the closest thing to what I need

Comment: Rather then using centre_x, would I just use x as its the name of the text input box

Comment: @PaulHesketh - In the original question - quote "I have 3 columns in my database - cityname, x, y" i.e. the table has x,y that is why I chose to use centre_x, centre_y